# Can two or more bosons concretely exist at the same exact point in space at the same time?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, wavefunction, bosons, quantum-statistics

Is it just the probability of finding the 2 particles in the same volume is the same or is it that they can really exist concretely as each other in the same point in time.

Also related is, can two distinct wave functions exist at the same point in space and time or do they always superpose?

Comment: No matter how many particles you are dealing with, they are always described by a single wavefunction $\Psi(x_1, \dots, x_N)$. We are only able to talk about separate wavefunctions in the very special case where this can be written $\psi_1(x_1) \dots \psi_N(x_N)$. Whether it can or not, the probabiltiy of any configuration with some $x_i = x_j$ will be zero because it is the integral of an $N$ variable function over an $N-1$ dimensional set.

Comment: Additional question, can two distinct quantum fields occupy the same space at the same time?

Comment: In every formalism I've seen, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, since bosons do not obey the Pauli Exclusion Principle. This means that two or more bosons can coexist at the exact same point in space at the same time.

Comment: That's only true for fundamental Bosons though. Composite Bosons that are made out of Fermions cannot be on exactly the same state at the same time.